# Cannot select AWS System Manager Automation documents shared between accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My org has 2 AWS accounts where we run EC2 instances. AccountA and AccountB.
I want to utilize the same Systems Manager automation documents that I created in AccountA in AccountB.
I opened the document_1 description, switched tab to details and then added AccountB's ID to the privately shared section, then hit save.
I switched to AccountB and found document_1 listed under the "shared with me" tab.
Great.
I switch to State Manager and go to create a new association to use document_1.
However the document list does not contain my document, so I cannot select it.
The same is true in "run command" and in "EventBridge rule targets". I've not yet found a UI where my shared documents show up.

I've tried searching for publicly shared documents (such as any of a dozen "helloworld" docs shared by various aws accounts), those also do not show up in the list.
The only non AWS document I've seen is this random "CrowdStrike-FalconSensorDeploy". I have no idea what is different or special about this one.

I also tried (just for the heck of it) making my document_1 public for a short while, but that didn't change anything.
The same behavior was observed for command documents. They could not be found when I tried searching for them in the document list. However clicking "Run Command" from the document description does actually find it.

I'm out of ideas.
It looks like a UI bug, but I could be wrong.
Is there any way to fix this, or should I start looking at command line options?